# Android: AnimatedVectorDrawable Loop

Tags: java, android, loops, animation, vector

I'm playing around with AnimatedVectorDrawables using https://shapeshifter.design/ The exported file I got is below. My research Tells me that in order to loop an animations i should add *android:repeatCount="infinite"* and *android:repeatMode="restart"* to the objectAnimator.

Adding this to the objectAnimator only repeats one of these items out of series. **How would I loop the entire series of animations?** I want the animation to start on load and repeat.

### Animation XML

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="50dp"
            android:height="50dp"
            android:viewportWidth="50"
            android:viewportHeight="50">
            <path
                android:name="_x34_"
                android:pathData="M 25 12.3 L 39.7 37.7 L 10.3 37.7 Z"
                android:fillColor="#ffffff"
                android:strokeColor="#000000"
                android:strokeWidth="1"
                android:strokeLineCap="round"
                android:strokeLineJoin="round"
                android:strokeMiterLimit="10"/>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="_x34_">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="M 25 12.3 L 39.7 37.7 L 10.3 37.7 L 17.397 25.437 Z"
                    android:valueTo="M 10 10 L 40 10 L 40 40 L 10 40 Z"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="M 40 10 L 25.581 10 L 10 10 L 10 40 L 25.349 40 L 40 40 L 40 10"
                    android:valueTo="M 36.3 18.7 L 25 10.4 L 13.7 18.7 L 12.8 31.5 L 25 39.6 L 37.2 31.5 L 36.3 18.7"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="2000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="M 36.3 18.7 L 25 10.4 L 13.7 18.7 L 12.8 31.5 L 25 39.6 L 37.2 31.5 Z"
                    android:valueTo="M 25 10.2 L 12.2 17.6 L 12.2 32.4 L 25 39.8 L 37.8 32.4 L 37.8 17.6 Z"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="3000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="M 31.365 13.88 L 25 10.2 L 18.268 14.092 L 12.2 17.6 L 12.2 25.465 L 12.2 32.4 L 25 39.8 L 37.8 32.4 L 37.8 25.581 L 37.8 17.6 L 31.365 13.88"
                    android:valueTo="M 33.7 13 L 25 10.2 L 16.3 13 L 10.9 20.4 L 10.9 29.6 L 16.3 37 L 25 39.8 L 33.7 37 L 39.1 29.6 L 39.1 20.4 L 33.7 13"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="4000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="M 39.1 20.4 L 33.7 13 L 25 10.2 L 16.3 13 L 10.9 20.4 L 10.9 29.6 L 16.3 37 L 25 39.8 L 33.7 37 L 39.1 29.6 L 39.1 20.4"
                    android:valueTo="M 39.7 20 L 32.199 16.173 L 25 12.5 L 17.885 16.13 L 10.3 20 L 10 31 L 16.994 34.031 L 25 37.5 L 32.948 34.056 L 40 31 L 39.7 20"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="5000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="M 10.3 20 L 25 12.5 L 39.7 20 L 40 31 L 25 37.5 L 10 31 L 10.3 20"
                    android:valueTo="M 17.995 24.403 L 25 12.3 L 32.23 24.792 L 39.7 37.7 L 25.581 37.7 L 10.3 37.7 L 17.995 24.403"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

### My java code for implementing the Animation is as follows:

```
final ImageView animationView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animationView);
final AnimatedVectorDrawable drawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.avd_dice);
animationView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
drawable.start();
```

Answer (score 25):

You should use `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat` instead of `AnimatedVectorDrawable` to support lower APIs, then you can also write that callback and start the animation when it ends.
Finally, your code should be like this:

```
    val animated = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this, R.drawable.avd_dice)
        animated?.registerAnimationCallback(object : Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
            override fun onAnimationEnd(drawable: Drawable?) {
                animated.start()
            }

        })
        animationView.setImageDrawable(animated)
        animated?.start()
```

Answer (score 19):

use property in your objectAnimator

```
android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
```

your object is like that

```
 <objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="pathData"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:valueFrom="path value"
    android:valueTo="some value"
    android:valueType="pathType"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"/>
```

Comment: This cause my animation works bad, I want to updown this answer but I cant, the good answer is at the bottom https://stackoverflow.com/a/50371439/3994630 from @Feryal Sharifzadeh

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The glitch that @PabloCegarra mentioned happens because of the overshoot interpolator. If you replace it with the linear interpolator, then the answer is not only simpler than the accepted one, but also smoother, because the restart is smoother it seems.

Comment: I have tons of <objectAnimator/> is there any chance to apply the repeat count and repeat mode for the whole xml file ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately setting interpolator on the <objectAnimator> [is not documented](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186135731), but it works!

Answer (score 18):

You can use [Animatable2.AnimationCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Animatable2.AnimationCallback.html) and start the AnimatedVectorDrawable animation again in onAnimationEnd

```
drawable.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
        avd.start();
    }
});

drawable.start();
```

Comment: Please note that it's API 23+

Comment: It is now available down to API 14 in support library 26.0.0

Comment: How do you invoke the support library @CarsonHolzheimer ? I have an app with min API level 21 (target 26), support library 27.x and I still get an error stating that I need min API level 23.

Comment: I think you'll have to add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in your build.gradle `defaultConfig`?

Comment: That seems to be the solution for supporting VectorDrawables on API < 21. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution

Comment: I found it necessary to call `animationView.post { avd.start() }` in `onAnimationEnd()` in order to get the loop working properly.

Credit to this article for the suggestion - https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/re-animation-7869722af206

Answer (score 6):

Using @Feryal Sharifzadeh great answer as a base, here's a Kotlin ext function for setting and looping a AVD.

```
internal fun ImageView.applyLoopingAnimatedVectorDrawable(@DrawableRes avdResId: Int) {
    val animated = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(context, avdResId)
    animated?.registerAnimationCallback(object : Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(drawable: Drawable?) {
            this@applyLoopingAnimatedVectorDrawable.post { animated.start() }
        }
    })
    this.setImageDrawable(animated)
    animated?.start()
}
```

Answer (score -5):

There are two ways in which you can use AnimatedVectorDrawable. One is by using a single file for all XML part. Second is using three separate files - one for the Vector part, second for the Animator part and the third for the AnimatedVectorDrawable part which joins the first two.

In my case I tried to use the single XML file alternative. But I had problems and lot of time was going in it. So I shifted to the second alternative i.e., three XML files alternative. It is working fine. Below I am explaining how you do it.

I dearly wished to give the code. But, I am not able to post the code due to some problem with indentation which the system at (stackoverflow) has not accepted.

Under AnimatedVectorDrawable class examples of all the three files are given in the android developer site.

I assume you want to do path morphing on two objects on the screen.

For path morphing on each path element in the VectorDrawable file there will be two pathData - from which to morph and to which to morph. So for two path elements in VectorDrawable file there will be 4 pathData which you can put under strings file with names like my_path_from1 my_path_to1, my_path_from2 and my_path_to2.

In vector drawable file the root element is vector under that you can place your two path elements - one for each object on the screen . Under these path elements you give attributes like strokeWidth, strokeColor pathData and a name. . This vector drawable file should be placed under res/drawable folder.

The second one is the animator file. this file should be placed under res/animator folder. You can have set as root element under which you can have one objectAnimator element in your present case. In this you give duration and pathData from which and pathData to which to do the morphing. These you give under attributes "android:valueFrom" and " android:valueTo" . You may create two animator files because "from" "to" pathData are different for the two path elements in the VectorDrawable file.

In the animated vector drawable file give two targets. Under each target the android:name is name of one of the path elements inthe VectorDrawable file. And under android:animation you give name of one of the animator files , i.e., say for first target you give android:animation ="@animator/first_animator". Similarlly for the second. Now because the two targets are in the same file both targets animate simultaneously. Both animations work on two different sets of path data because the two animation files are also different.

In the java code findViewById your ImageView. If you inflated it as View then you will have to type cast it as imageview. Then getDrawable from the image view. Now if drawable instanceOf Animatable then drawable.start().

Hope this helps you.

For a very good understanding of these animations you may please refer to "introduction to icon animation techniques" This is at

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the OP's question; how can you make the animation loop?